# Не могу пройти Аутентификацию на бирже OKEX

Tags: excel, api, rest, vba, access

Всем добрый день. Целый день помучался - патаюсь пройти аутентификацию на бирже OKEX через API. Сделано все как описано https://www.okex.com/docs/en/#summary-yan-zheng. Прошу тыкните пальцем что не так я делаю.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Const linkServer = "https://www.okex.com"
Const sApiKey1 = "3d7f03c3-...7"
Const sSign = "59...E7"
Const sPass = "kZ...cgj"
Const sText = "VBA_ACCESS_002"


Function getServerInfo(strZapros As String) As String

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = linkServer & strZapros
    Debug.Print strUrl
    blnAsync = True

    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send
        While objRequest.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    Set objRequest = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print strResponse
    getServerInfo = strResponse
End Function

Function getParametr(sPrm As String, sData As String) As Variant
Dim dStartPrm As Integer
Dim dStartData, dEndData As Integer
Dim dOut As String

    dStartPrm = InStr(1, sData, sPrm)
    dStartData = InStr(dStartPrm, sData, ":""")
    dEndData = InStr(dStartData + 2, sData, """")
    dOut = Mid(sData, dStartData + 2, dEndData - dStartData - 2)
    getParametr = dOut
End Function

Function getServerTimeNano() As String
Dim sData As String
Dim sOut As String
    
    sData = getServerInfo("/api/general/v3/time")
    sOut = getParametr("iso", sData)
    getServerTimeNano = sOut
End Function



Sub verifacationAccaunt()
Dim sData1 As String
Dim sIso As String, sEpoch As String
Dim sVerZapros As String

Dim sData As String
Dim sOut As String
    
    sData = getServerInfo("/api/general/v3/time")
    sIso = getParametr("iso", sData)
    sEpoch = getParametr("epoch", sData)
  

    sData1 = getServerVerif("/api/spot/v5/accounts", sIso, sEpoch)
End Sub

Function getServerVerif(strZapros As String, sIso As String, sEpoch As String) As String

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim sMes  As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = linkServer & strZapros
    Debug.Print strUrl
    blnAsync = True
    sMes = getSecretMes(sIso, "GET", strZapros, "")
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "OK-ACCESS-KEY", sApiKey1
        .SetRequestHeader "OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", sPass
        .SetRequestHeader "OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", sIso
        .SetRequestHeader "OK-ACCESS-SIGN", sMes
        '.SetRequestHeader "x-simulated-trading", "0"
        
        Debug.Print "sApiKey1 ", sApiKey1
        Debug.Print "sPass ", sPass
        Debug.Print "sIso ", sIso
        Debug.Print "sMes ", sMes
        .Send
           
        While objRequest.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    Set objRequest = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print strResponse
    getServerVerif = strResponse
End Function

Function getSecretMes(sTime As String, sMode As String, sUrl As String, sBody As String) As String
    getSecretMes = Base64_HMACSHA256(sTime & sMode & sUrl, sSign)
End Function

Sub asdf()
    getSecret getServerTimeNano
End Sub

Public Function Base64_HMACSHA256(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String)
    Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
 
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
 
    TextToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(sTextToHash) '"59CD46C1244645E4BAA79C2C5354E4E7"
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(sSharedSecretKey) '"2021-06-16T16:04:37.916ZGET/api/spot/v5/accounts"
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey 'H1Nq0n1nSlrMyW5ZqCsGp0XSjwQQYTrqYy3UZtBwNj0=
 
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    Base64_HMACSHA256 = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
End Function
 
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String
 
    'Inside the VBE, Go to Tools -> References, then Select Microsoft XML, v6.0
    '(or whatever your latest is. This will give you access to the XML Object Library.)
 
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
 
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
 
    ' byte array to base64
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text
 
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
 
End Function
```

Comment: Server OKEX возвращает **Forbidden**

Comment: Основная процедура **verifacationAccaunt**